# Results of previous update returned on mysql select in Python3

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have one script running on a server that updates a list of items in a MySQL database to be processed by another script running on my desktop. The script runs in a loop, processing the list every 5 minutes (the server side script also runs on a 5 minute cycle). On the first loop, the script retrieves the current list (basic SELECT operation), on the second cycle, it gets the same version (not updated) list, on the third, it gets the list it should have gotten on the second pass. On every pass after the first, the SELECT operation returns the data from the previous UPDATE operation.

```
def mainFlow():
    activeList=[]
    d=()
    a=()
    b=()
    #cycleStart=datetime.datetime.now()
    cur = DBSV.cursor(buffered=True)
    cur.execute("SELECT list FROM active_list WHERE id=1")
    d=cur.fetchone()
    DBSV.commit()
    a=d[0]
    b=a[0]
    activeList=ast.literal_eval(a)
    print(activeList)
    buyList=[]

    clearOrders()
    sellDecide()    
    if activeList:
        for i in activeList:
            a=buyCalculate(i)
            if a:
                buyList.append(i)
        print ('buy list: ',buyList)    
    if buyList:
        buyDecide(buyList)
    cur.close()
    d=()
    a=()
    b=()
    activeList=[]

    print ('+++++++++++++END OF BLOCK+++++++++++++++')


state=True
while state==True:
    cycleStart=datetime.datetime.now()
    mainFlow()
    cycleEnd=datetime.datetime.now()
    wait=300-(cycleEnd-cycleStart).total_seconds()
    print ('wait=: ' +str(wait))
    if wait>0:
        time.sleep(wait)
```

As you can see, I am re initializing all my variables, I am closing my cursor, I am doing a commit() operation that is supposed to solve this sort of problem, I have tried plain cursors, and cursors with the buffer set True and False, always with the same result.

When I run the exact same Select query from MySQL Workbench, the results returned are fine.

Baffled, and stuck on this for 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

You're performing your COMMIT before your UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE transactions

Though a SELECT statement is, theoretically, [DML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) it has certain differences with INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE in that it doesn't modify the data within the database. If you want to see the data that has been changed within another session then you must COMMIT it only *after* it's been changed. This is partially exacerbated by you closing the cursor after each loop.

You've gone far too far in trying to solve this problem; there's no need to reset everything within the `mainFlow()` method (and I can't see a need for most of the variables)

```
def mainFlow():

    buyList = []

    cur = DBSV.cursor(buffered=True)
    cur.execute("SELECT list FROM active_list WHERE id = 1")

    activeList = cur.fetchone()[0]
    activeList = ast.literal_eval(activeList)

    clearOrders()
    sellDecide()    

    for i in activeList:
        a = buyCalculate(i)
        if a:
            buyList.append(i)

    if buyList:
        buyDecide(buyList)

    DBSV.commit()
    cur.close()

while True:

    cycleStart = datetime.datetime.now()
    mainFlow()
    cycleEnd = datetime.datetime.now()

    wait = 300 - (cycleEnd - cycleStart).total_seconds()

    if wait > 0:
        time.sleep(wait)
```

I've removed a fair amount of unnecessary code (and added spaces), I've removed the reuse of variable names for different things and the declaration of variables that are overwritten immediately. This still isn't very OO though...

As we don't have detailed knowledge of exactly what `clearOrders()`, `sellDecide()` and `buyCalculate()` you might want to double check this yourself.

Comment: Amazing. I still don't fully understand how changing where the close() and commit() are placed changes the returned results, but it works, and I'll take it!

Comment: When you commit your transaction you're posting the changes to the database; on your first cycle you don't post the changes, on the second you post the non-changes for the first and on the third you select the changes that you posted initially (or something like that).